What is triggering a Custom Function execution?
I have a function that is supposed to only run when called by a menu click. But it is being executed many many times, and even without even clicking on the menu item on the sheet itself.



I originally had this function as a custom function to be executed on the target sheet as a formula in a cell (=extractFormulas(parm)), but decided that it would be more efficient to call it only once (from a menu) and iterate through the rows in question, writing the results in the sheet using setValue(result). But somehow it seems as if the sheet has a memory and executes it as a cell custom function.
function onOpen() {    //create menu item
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Reconcile_Bank')
    .addItem('Get amounts from bank', 'extractFormulas')
    .addToUi();
}

function extractFormulas() {
  Logger.log('*********Starting extractFormulas()************');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Jan");
  const lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const receiptsRange = sheet.getRange("C5:C" + lrow);
  var budgetEntries = receiptsRange.getValues();
  var budgetFormulas = receiptsRange.getFormulas();
  var result = '';
  var amount = 0;
  var idx = '';

  for (j=29; j<lrow; j++) {
    result = '';
    amount = sheet.getRange(j,12).getValue();
    Logger.log('row: '+ j + ' amount: '+ amount);
    if (amount = 0) continue;
    if (amount > 0) 
      result = 'deposit';
    else {
      idx = budgetFormulas.findIndex(([c]) => [...c.matchAll(/\b[.\d]*/g)].some(([e]) => e == -amount.toString()));
      if (idx > -1) {
        result = receiptsRange.offset(idx, 0, 1, 1).getA1Notation()+"|"+receiptsRange.offset(idx, -1, 1, 1).getValue();
        Logger.log('Formula found: '+result);
        continue;    //refers to outer loop for (j=29; j<lrow; j++) {
      }
      else  //not in a formula
        for (var i = 0; i<budgetEntries.length; i++) {
          if (budgetEntries[i][0].toString() == -amount.toString()) {
            result = 'C'+(i+5)+'|'+sheet.getRange(i+5,2).getValue();
            Logger.log('non-Formula found '+ result + 'matched to '+budgetEntries[i][0].toString());
            break;  //refers to inner loop for (var i = 0; i<budgetEntries.length; i++) {
          }
        }
    } 
    if (result == '') 
      result = 'not found';
    sheet.getRange(j,9).setValue(result);
  }
  return;
}


A  custom function normally executes when it detects a change in the input parmeters.  What you are describing is not a Custom Function.  It appears that you are placing a standard scripting function into a cell and attempting to execute is from a click event. I don't think that will work.  - Custom Functions

Thanks for the suggestion @Cooper. I dont have the function in a cell, it is only referenced from the menu (see onOpen() function above). But because I originally had it as a Custom Function being called from a cell, maybe even though I have removed those cell calls, that somehow the sheet 'remembers'. I could change the function name to properly distinguish it from the original Custom Function

Your execution log suggests that you have not removed all of the custom functions.  Try changing the name of the function and you should be able to  see the errors on your spreadsheet

I did that (changed the name of the function), and the aberrant behaviour stopped. The puzzling thing is, the original name (extractFormulas) was NOT in the sheet, proven by doing a Find on the sheet for the name. As I said before, very puzzling, can only think it is because somehow the workspace retains knowledge of cells previous contents

"Find" - Did you checkbox "Search inside formulas" option?

@Lime  Make sure NOT to remove actual data like screenshot of Executions when making photos inline.

As the execution logs show "Custom Function" in the Type column, your spreadsheet still has formulas, including extractFormulas as a formula function.
Please remove this function from all the formulas, even those in hidden sheets.
You could use the UI Search function by checking Also search within formulas. Another option is to use Apps Script to find which formulas use this function.
It's worth noting that your script has at least one syntax error: using = (if (amount = 0) continue;) instead of == or ===.

Thanks @wicket, yes I picked up that error, took me a while though, inconsistent with other languages
